# How do I create a variable cursor inside a store procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am writing a procedure to process a MySQL table which name depends on the day, with the form `cdr_20131108`. My procedure should be able to do some operations from any given date's table.

All those tables have the same structure, and include a `time` field. For every row, I need to check how many rows meet some criteria in the previous hour. As far as I know, I need a cursor to find the time of the current row, as well as some more data, and then prepare and execute a query, from which I'll find my results.

In pseudo-code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myproc`()
BEGIN

DECLARE all necessary variables to save the data returned by the cursor    

DECLARE c1 cursor for
    select required fields
    from cdr_20131103
    where some criteria;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET _done = TRUE;

set @tablename := concat('rm_cdrs',date_format(curdate(),'%Y%m%d'));
set @entries := 0;

open c1;
c1_loop: loop
    fetch c1 into my variables;
    if `_done` then leave c1_loop; end if;      
    set @q := concat('... my query is prepared here: select count(*) into @variable (
                        select in which i look for rows that meet my criteria that 
                        happened less tan an hour before the one in the cursor)');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;    EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  if some criteria is met then do some stuff...

end loop c1_loop;
close c1;

END
```

So my problem arises when I need to check today's table without tweaking the code, as MySQL won't let me use a variable here:

```
DECLARE c1 cursor for
select required fields
from cdr_20131103
where some criteria;
```

I tried creating a procedure that generates the required procedure with the correct table name here, but MySQL won't let me DROP or ALTER a procedure from a stored routine.

Is there any workaround in this case?

- Can I avoid using a cursor in this case?
- Should I perform the cursor's task manually, as explained [here](http://sekarpdkt.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/mysql-work-around-for-handling-variables-in-cursor/)?
- This procedure will probably called periodically using cron. Should I just code some Java/C/PHP app that creates and calls the correct procedure after dropping the old one?

Thank you very much!

---

**EDIT:**

@Sebas states that it's possible to perform this operations by using a single insert-select statement. Although the view trick in his answer works like a charm, I would like to try and learn from this. I'll add a Little more information:

When selecting the interesting columns and using a where clause to filter out the data, `cdr_20131103` looks like the following:

```
+---------+----------------+--------+
| user_ID | destination_ID |  time  |
+---------+----------------+--------+
|       2 |             56 | 110312 |
|       4 |             53 | 110513 |
|       2 |             56 | 110821 |
|       2 |             56 | 113212 | *
|       2 |             56 | 123001 |
+---------+----------------+--------+
```

I need to find out when the same user_ID has accessed the same destination_ID at least 3 times within an hour. Therefore, the row with `*` should be inserted in another table, along with a now() field.

My linear mind tells me I should process the rows one by one, compute the initial time (`time - interval 1 hour`, select the rows with same User_ID and destination_ID in that time lapse, count them and eventual insert them into the other table.

Is there a better way to do this in SQL?

Thank you very very much!

Comment: we might find a simpler workaround. `if some criteria is met then do some stuff...` What stuff?

Comment: Hi @Sebas! Sorry if I skipped some information, I was trying to keep this simple and readable! In that part, if `@variable > @N` (being @N a parameter previously obtained from another query), I insert some of columns in the current cursor into another table (Row Id, Numbers, etc.). Thank you very much!

Comment: What about insert/select then? With a global select including the count and the query of the cursor, you can insert datas in any table matching your conditions. All in one query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Sebas Thank you! Is it posible to use insert-select when I need to perform a query based in the results of a previous one? For every row in the table, I need to check how many similar ones appear in the previous hour, i.e. I find the criteria for the second query from the data obtained in the cursor.

Comment: yes of course. Sometimes mysql is limited but I think we can work it out

Comment: @Sebas I've added some more information in the question. I'm very grateful for this, I am learning a lot!

Comment: is your system h24 or h12? also, what's the column type of `time`

Comment: Do you need to insert in the other table the `time` value or is it just `NOW()`?

Comment: time is char, I am using time(time) every time I need to compare or substract an hour to find the interval. It is h24. I only save now() datetime on the result. table. Thank you!

Comment: Then see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do all you want with one single `select insert` SQL. Investigate something like this (assuming `tabletoinsert`, assuming the column type of `time` is `VARCHAR`)

```
INSERT INTO tabletoinsert
SELECT user_id, destination_id, SUBSTRING(time, 1, 2) AS hour, NOW()
FROM cdr_20131103
GROUP BY user_id, destination_id, SUBSTRING(time, 1, 2)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

But you can also use a dirty trick if you really need a cursor:

1- Create a view dynamically, in another stored procedure

```
SET @dyn_sql = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `v_yourview` AS ', 
                               SELECT required fields
                               FROM cdr_', date_format(curdate(),'%Y%m%d'), ' WHERE some criteria;');

PREPARE stmt_dyn_view FROM @dyn_sql;
EXECUTE stmt_dyn_view;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_dyn_view;
```

2- use it in the cursor of your main procedure:

```
DECLARE c1 cursor for
    select required fields
    from v_yourview
    where some criteria;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it working using a view. Is this efficient? Using a view has saved me a bunch of lines, as well as reducing the number of conditions I need to check in my queries.

Comment: yes a view is as efficient as the underlying query is. It does not add any storage requirements, just the `CREATE VIEW GRANT` (or maybe the `CREATE TABLE` is enough?).

Comment: Hi @Sebas! Thank you for the invaluable help. I have been trying this for a while. Although it's a very neat way to find entries in natural hours (e.g. 11:00-11:59), I don't think it would detect it in other cases, such as 11:30-12:20. I have tried to achieve this by using `having count(*)>=3 and timediff(max(time(mytime)),min(time(mytime)))<'010000'`. This works alright when I have entries at 10:02, 10:05 and 10:50; but fails if I add another one at 11:20. I see why. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Why are you not using the SUBSTR version?